# Authentication and Authorization of user by WSO2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, wso2

We want to use WSO2 AM or IS for authentication and authorization.

We have below main requirements.

- WSO2 should be able to Authenticate user
- We want to configure API access level in WSO2 example: ROLE based
  Authorization (or Policy based ) where we can configure who can
  access which web API with Http verb. (In the WSO2 API management,
  each user have to subscribe the publish api but I do not want to give
  the subscription process for the user)
- We should be able dynamically to add/update/delete users, update
  Authorization policies/ roles through WSO2 API.
- A user can generate a token by rest call and they can access all
  application without subscribing Any api.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking. Try to formulate a question

Comment: I wants to use WSO2am as getway for my APIs and I can used this API in frontend of my application..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these features are available out of the box in WSO2 API Manager. Please go through the following document.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Quick+Start+Guide

Comment: But according to this doc user have to subscribe the API for using it but I wants to use WSO2am as getway and I don't want to  give subscription process for user. User can only register , login and then use every API without subscribe it

Comment: Could you please explain the real use case here? A subscription between an application and an API means that this API will be used within the application. So your requirement sounds very strange.

Comment: According to my requirements
Angular ---->WSO2am----> backend
User can Authorize user can access service on angular UI and Authorization and authentication is done by WSO2am getway....and user should not used the API store for subscribing the API

Comment: By 'user' I think you meant the application user. They don't need to subscribe to the API. Only the person who develops the Angular app needs to subscribe. Once that's done, your application can generate tokens for its users using the token API. Is it clear?

Comment: But that token is same for all application user but I wants to generate different different token for each application user like developer token and that token is authorised by WSO2am

Comment: You can generate separate tokens for each user. You need to pick a correct grant type for that. For example, the password grant type. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Password+Grant

By default in the UI we use the client-credentials grant type which generates a token for the application but not for users. Password grant should cater to your requirement.